# Response.ClearHeaders() replacement for .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have used `Response.ClearHeaders();` in a Controller action method. But it returns an error like:

> 'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'ClearHeaders' and no accessible extension method 'ClearHeaders' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpResponse' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can you please help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the `Response.Clear()` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.responseextensions.clear) instead.

> This invocation resets the response headers, response status code, and response body.

Comment: Or, given that he seems to just want to clear the headers, just `Response.Headers.Clear()` , which is what the extension method ends up calling for the headers.

Comment: Strange - [the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iheaderdictionary) don't list `Clear` as a method or extension method for the `IHeaderDictionary` interface. Also, I suspect it would be odd to want to clear the headers *without* also clearing the body.

Comment: It's not an extension method, but because `IHeaderDictionary` derives from `IDictionary`, which has `Clear`.